# pass data from parent to another component injected into child component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i would like pass data from parent to another component injected into child component, how can I do that ?.

Without using the route or a service.

thanks you.

**parent.component**

```
<div class"container">
  <app-child></app-child> // My app-child-one injected here
  <app-childTwo></app-childTwo>
</div>
```

**child.component**

```
<div class"container">
 <app-child-one></app-child-one>
</div>
```

Comment: Passing data from parent to child is usually done using an @Input()..?

Comment: But in my case is child into child

Comment: In React this it is called something like props chaining, in Angular you can use ngrx (not suggested), or services better than chaining inputs. If you have opportunity to implement the data in child component rather than parent, that would be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I don't fully understand your requirement, what's keeping you from just using [Input()-Properties](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)?

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-child [someProperty]="value"></app-child> // My app-child-one injected here
  <app-childTwo></app-childTwo>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <app-child-one [someProperty]="value"></app-child-one>
</div>
```

This, of course, means that **both**, `AppChildOneComponent` and `AppChildComponent` need `someProperty` as an input-property, thus "pushing" that property down the tree step by step.